# M1 printing causing USB devices to disconnect

Tags: hard-drive, printing, apple-silicon

I have an old HP LaserJet 1022 printer (15 years old) that is still alive and doing great. Ever since I bought an M1 Mac, printing to the printer creates an issue.

The document prints fine, but after a couple of seconds my mouse will freeze for 3 seconds, my external hard drive will disconnect, and then everything goes back to normal. The mouse, printer, and hard drive are all connected via a [Kensington USB-C hub SD5700T](https://www.kensington.com/internal-support-pages/sd5700t-support-page/).

Any ideas on how to stop this issue? I worry that disconnecting/reconnecting the hard drive numerous times per day will cause it to die faster.

Thanks!

Comment: did you try changing the cable or using another port

Comment: Sounds like a possible issue with the printer driver. Have you tried a generic (EG: built-in to macOS) HP or Postscript driver?

Comment: @Ruskes Yes, I tried that.

Comment: @SteveChambers I tried researching what you've said here but it didn't work. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: On my macOS 12.6, click on the "+" button and select your printer in the list. Select your printer in the list. From the "Use" menu "Auto Select" and once it selects the right driver change it to use generic PCL or PostScript printer.

Comment: @SteveChambers I'm on macOS 11.1. For me my Use options are: 'Auto Select' is grayed out, Select Software, and Other.